# How can I add a background to a pattern in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am currently working with Highcharts in combination with the pattern fill module. When I set a pattern for a series in the chart, the pattern is shown but it has a transparent background. I need to set an additional background because the pattern is overlapping with another series which I don't want to see behind it. You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/651nhfsx/2/). So basically I don't want to see those three columns on the left behind the pattern. Any ideas how I can do that? I haven't seen any options to set an additional background, but maybe you know some trick. This is the code I am using for the pattern:

```
     "color": {
        "pattern": {
          "path": {
            "d": "M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11"
          },
          "width": 10,
          "height": 10,
          "opacity": 1,
          "color": "rgb(84,198,232)"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `fill` attribute as a path property:

```
        "color": {
            "pattern": {
                "path": {
                    "d": "M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11",
                    fill: 'red'
                },
                "width": 10,
                "height": 10,
                "opacity": 1,
                "color": 'rgb(84,198,232)'
            }
        }
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m9rxwej5/

Answer (score 2):

I guess there's been an update. backgroundColor should be set at pattern's root level:

```
"color": {
        "pattern": {
            "backgroundColor": 'red',
            "path": {
                "d": "M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11",
            },
            "width": 10,
            "height": 10,
            "opacity": 1,
            "color": 'rgb(84,198,232)',
        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vL4fqhao/

Comment: I confirm that this is the correct property https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.PatternOptionsObject#backgroundColor